# Is it possible create data base using only JDK? Without external libaries?

Tags: java, database

I have got question. Cen you tell me is it possible create data base using only JDK? Without external libaries? I look for information in the internet and I think that i have to import for example mysql via Maven. But please tell me: it possible create data base using only JDK?

EDIT: Data in normal files (like txt) is not this for what I am looking for.

Comment: Is it possible? Absolutely. Is it sensible? No, unless you're doing it simply as an exercise to understand how database engines are implemented.

Comment: You can use databases that support ODBC connectivity. Something like MS Access should be usable without any external driver libraries.

Comment: I expect that this unsensible. I done everything in my progam od MySQL and it work, but like you said: it is exercise. I should rebuild my code. Something like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GDj3NTSAtMU ?

Comment: _"Data in normal files (like txt) is not this for what I am looking for"_ -- ALL files are "data in normal files", even databases. They may not be readable text, but it's still all "data" and lives in "normal files".

Comment: @Jim Garrison Of course you are right. I meane that i dont want use Scaner to get info from file but I want something like MySQL with query execution and all this stuf.

Comment: Regardless of its ubiquity, `Scanner` is IMHO useless.  In nearly 25 years of writing Java code I've never _once_ found a need to use `Scanner`.  As to rewriting MySQL in Java, @jsheeran is right.  It would take you literally years, possibly decades, maybe even centuries, to accomplish by yourself.  I'm sure databases like MySQL, Postgres, etc are the result of millions of person-hours.

Comment: Think about it this way: nearly _all_ libraries eventually boil down to the JDK. If you copied guava's code into your own, you wouldn't be using a library. The only things that aren't eventually JDK are those that incorporate native code (using JNI), but you can definitely build a database without that.

Comment: All dependencies in maven is external libaries too? I am right?

Comment: Sure, but you could conceptually just keep copying those dependencies in and in. Basically, everything has to either boil down to JDK or JNI. There's nothing magic about libraries; they're still code, just code you didn't write.

Comment: Thats right. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Apache Derby** comes included in the standard JDK installation.

You need to load it, however, in the classpath. It's at `JDK_HOME/db/lib/derby.jar`. Derby is a quite powerful database that can be started from inside any Java program.

To start it, your Java program uses a JDBC URL that includes the path of a directory. All tables and data are stored in that specific directory.

So, you'll use standard JDBC. The details are:

- **Driver Class**: org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
- **URL**: jdbc:derby:my_database1
- **Username**: *any-username-you-like*
- **Password**: *any-password-you-like*

*my_database1* is the name of the directory where files will be stored. Use any username/password combination.

Comment: Ok, I will try it. Is there in SDK another class for PDF generation to avoid using external libaries?

Comment: Not that I know of. You can add itext-pdf.jar. Freely available.